# MERGE Conditional THEN UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables: Master and Source. Both tables have 3 columns. They are ID, Item Description and List Price. The 'Source' table has a few nulls in Item Description.

What I want to do is to merge the Source table into the Master. However, if the description field in the Source table is null, then do not change the description in the Master table.

Is there a better way of re-writing this? It looks a bit repetitive.This is my attempt.

```
    Breakdown:
    1) When matched and if description in source is null, only update id 
       and price
    2) When matched update
    3) Insert into Master table if Source table has new ids



MERGE INTO MASTER AS MS
USING       SOURCE AS SRC
ON        (MS.id = SRC.id)
WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.item_deSRC is NULL THEN
UPDATE SET MS.id = SRC.id
           MS.List_Price = SRC.List_Price
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET MS.id = SRC.id
,          MS.Description = SRC.Description
,          MS.List_Price = SRC.List_Price
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES(MS.id, MS.description, MS.List_Price)
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. I assume you attempt does not work in some fashion. Does it error? What is the result set that is bad?

Comment: Also, should we assume INMSRT is a typo in the question, not your actual problem?

Comment: Sorry! it's a typo. I was wondering is there a better way of re-writing this? It looks a bit repetitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get an error doing this that looks like:

Msg 10714, Level 15, State 1, Line 
An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.

Instead of

```
WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.item_deSRC is NULL THEN
UPDATE SET MS.id = SRC.id
           MS.List_Price = SRC.List_Price
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET MS.id = SRC.id
,          MS.Description = SRC.Description
,          MS.List_Price = SRC.List_Price
```

try

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET MS.Description = ISNULL(SRC.Description,MS.Description)
          ,MS.List_Price = SRC.List_Price
```

That should be correct, less repetitive, and drops the extraneous "SET MS.id = SRC.id"

Comment: Ah! This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Very elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, your `WHEN MATCHED` clauses can really be merged very simply into one clause [as Karl Kieninger explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23177814/521799). If, however, your two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses differ heavily depending on the predicates that you're using, then you can emulate standard SQL's capability of using multiple `WHEN MATCHED` clauses like this, [as I've also shown in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/10/the-many-flavours-of-the-arcane-sql-merge-statement/).

For example, if you want to do something like this (where `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` are some predicates):

```sql
WHEN MATCHED AND p1 THEN UPDATE SET c1 = 1
WHEN MATCHED AND p2 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND p3 THEN UPDATE SET c1 = 3, c2 = 3
WHEN MATCHED AND p4 THEN DELETE
```

Then you would have to re-write the above to the following set of `WHEN MATCHED` clauses using `CASE` expressions and combinations on `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`

```sql
WHEN MATCHED AND
  p1 OR
  NOT p1 AND NOT p2 AND p3
THEN UPDATE SET
  c1 = CASE
    WHEN p1                       THEN 1
    WHEN NOT p1 AND NOT p2 AND p3 THEN 3
                                  ELSE c1
  END,
  c2 = CASE
    WHEN NOT p1 AND NOT p2 AND p3 THEN 3
                                  ELSE c2
  END
WHEN MATCHED AND
  NOT p1 AND p2 OR
  NOT p1 AND NOT p2 AND NOT p3 AND p4
THEN DELETE
```